# Working with structures and hashes in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider the following structure in Perl: (let's call it declaration `A`)

```
my $json_struct = {
    name => $name,
    time => $time,
};
```

I have a hash `%hash` which contains custom fields (I don't know how many). It looks something like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
         'key2' => '123',
         'key1' => 'abc',
         'key3' => 'xwz'
    };
```

I would like to loop through the hash keys and insert those keys into the structure, so I thought that I can do something like this:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
  push @{ $json_struct }, { $key => $hash{$key} };
}
```

I'm not sure that it is working as expected. Also, is there a cleaner way to do so? Maybe I can combine it in one or two lines while declaring `A`.?

Expected output: (order does not matter)

```
$VAR1 = {
         'name' => $name,
         'time' => $time,
         'key2' => '123',
         'key1' => 'abc',
         'key3' => 'xwz'
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$json_struct` is a hash reference, but `@{ $json_struct }` performs *array* dereferencing on `$json_struct`, so that is not going to work.

There is no `push` operator for hashes; you just insert new data by assigning values to new keys. For your structure, you would just want to say

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    $json_struct->{$key} = $hash{$key};
}
```

Now you *can* also use the `@{...}` operator to specify a [*hash slice*](https://metacpan.org/pod/perldata#Slices), which may be what you were thinking of. Hash slices can be used to operate on several keys of a hash simultaneously. The syntax that will work for you for that operation is

```
@{$json_struct}{keys %hash} = values %hash;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the hash is empty, it will still work as expected? ($json_struct will contain only name and time?)

Comment: Yes, no iterations of the `foreach` loop would run and the empty hash slice would be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to join hashes is like this:

```
my $foo = {
    name => $name,
    time => $time,
};

my $bar = {
         'key2' => '123',
         'key1' => 'abc',
         'key3' => 'xwz'
    };

my $combined = {
    %{$foo},
    %{$bar},
};
```